# Is $Hom(-.A)$ exact?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $A=k[[x_1,\cdots,x_n]]$ be the ring of power series in $n$ variables over a field of characteristic zero $k$. Let 
$$\mathcal{C}=\cdots\rightarrow P_{v+1}\rightarrow P_v\rightarrow P_{v-1}\cdots$$
be a complex of projective modules such that the $v-$th homology is also projective for all $v$ and the connecting morphisms in the homology complex are all zero . Let $-^*=Hom(-,A)$ stand for the dual functor and consider the dual complex $$\mathcal{C}^*=\cdots\rightarrow P_{v-1}^*\rightarrow P_v^*\rightarrow P_{v+1}^*\cdots$$ Is it true that the $v-$th homology in $\mathcal{C}^*$ is equal to $H_v^*$ where $H_v$ is the $v-$th homology in $\mathcal{C}$?